# Attempting to move with nerve block? Harmful?

Tags: nerves, nervous-system

Today I had surgery on my shoulder to repair my torn labrum. After the surgery, I had the option of receiving a nerve block, which I took.

I have been periodically attempting to move my fingers despite the nerve block not having worn off yet. Sometimes I try to move my fingers with fair determination (trying pretty hard) and I feel mild to moderate tingling (corresponds to how *hard* I try) in my wrist and hand which dissipates quickly.

Is trying frequently or with decent effort harmful? Can it damage anything? Am I free to keep trying or should I wait until the block is worn off?

Comment: Were you given instructions on how to care for your shoulder? Were you told anything about moving your fingers?

Comment: All I was told was that the nerve block would make my entire arm numb and that I wouldn't be able to move it until the block wore off.